# WEH65 Smart Device Platform development

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-mobile, windows-ce

at our Company we develop Application for WEH Scanners. Since all of the devices Targets Windows CE 5/6/7 (including WEH65) we are forced to use Visual Studio 2008.
At the begining of 2014 we started to evaluating Visual Studio 2013 as the developing IDE for Smart Device Applications. Quickly I realized that this doesn't work, since Microsoft didn't integrate the Smart Device Platform in the new IDE.

So, what can we do? 
**Good News**, I will post the answer by my self, because after 2 Months of analyzing different debug engine implementations I have a more or less full working Solution ;)

Comment: FYI: you can answer your own question immediately by checking the *Answer your own question* box at the bottom when asking a question.

Comment: Thank you, but at the Moment I don't have 15 Reputation and can't answer my own question immediately :( I have to wait 8 hours

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the rep restriction.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is not the Compiler, the Problem are the following components:

1. Debugger
2. Forms Designer
3. Project Sub-Type

**Debugger**

You have to create a custom PortSupplier. This PortSupplier have to create the Connection to the Device with the Remote Tools Framework

**Forms Designer**

You have to create a ProjectType which replaces the Default Forms Designer with the Designer from VS2008 for Smart Devices.

**Project Sub Type**

Since the Project SubType (4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884) is unknown by VS2013, you have to create a custom Project Flavor. In this custom Project Flavor you have to Combine the PortSupplier with the ProjectSubtype. You also have to Implement the IVsDeployableProjectCfg for automated assembly deployment and IVsDebuggableProjectCfg for debuuging.

**Dependencies**

Since the Emulator(s) and the Forms Designer are a part of VS2008 you still have to install a VS2008 on your development machine. 
You also need the .NET CF RemoteToolsFrmework 3.5 since the Remote Calls are offered by this component.

**So the Problem is solved, we can develop .NET CompactFramework Application with VS2013.**

Comment: This is far too wordy to be of much use; reading this, I have no idea what you did to solve the issue... you should include a bulleted list of what you did to fix the issue.  If the issue isn't fixed, tihs isn't an answer.  Also, regarding "If there are some interested people I will offer a demo VSIX on visualstudiogallery in the next weeks", that's not how Stack Overflow works -- answers should be completely self-contained here.  Offering demos smells like an advertisement.

Comment: Better, but as I said before, answers should be completely self-contained here.  That means links to off-site resources are not allowed.  **ALL** relevant information should be in this answer, including any information in the csharp-devs blog.

Comment: again, and now without the link. Everything is explained in the answer.